# C++ member template specialization syntax

Tags: c++, templates

On [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) there is the following paragraph:

> When defining a member of an explicitly specialized class template outside the body of the class, the syntax template <> is not used, except if it's a member of an explicitly specialized member class template, which is specialized as a class template, **because otherwise, the syntax would require such definition to begin with template< parameters > required by the nested template**.

I do not know what the highlighted section means. Does "otherwise" refer to the general case (in which template<> is not used) or to the exception case (in which template<> must be used)?

I would appreciate an explanation of that section.

Answer (score -1):

This will be our template:

```
template< typename T>
struct A {
    struct B {};  // member class 
    template<class U> struct C { }; // member class template
};
```

See the following code:

```
template<> // specialization
struct A<int> {
    void f(int); // member function of a specialization
};
// template<> not used for a member of a specialization
void A<int>::f(int) { /* ... */ }
```

We are not using `template<>` while defining the member of a specialization, as this is a normal member class.

But, now see the next code:

```
template<> // specialization of a member class template
template<class U> struct A<char>::C {
    void f();
};

// template<> is used when defining a member of an explicitly
// specialized member class template specialized as a class template
template<>
template<class U> void A<char>::C<U>::f() { /* ... */ }
```

Here we are specializing a **member template** of the defined template. That is why we will need to use `template<>` to pass the parameters that this member template needs. In this case `class U` is needed for defining our member template, so for passing that we will need the keyword `template<>`.

Comment: But what would be the problem if the last definition did not use template<>?

Comment: for defining `C`, you need `U`. How will you pass that to it?

Comment: Does "template<class U> void A<char>::C<U>::f() { /* ... */ }" violate some syntax rules?

Comment: the first rule of template specialixation is including `template<>` above, but in 1st case we are defining just a normal class not any template so `template<>` was not used. But in 2nd case, we are defining a template, so it is required to have a `template<>` there.

Comment: What I don't understand is why template<> is needed in the exception case (defining member of specialization of member class template).

Comment: because it's a **TEMPLATE** not any class or basic data type.

Comment: and syntax is defined likewise